# Usage of the word "curious" in the meaning of peculiar: always correct or only as 'artistic' form?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

To me the word "curious" would be something you can be i.e.

> I am curious what tomorrow will bring

I recently read a text of a student I was supervising which used it as follows

> A curious phenomenon is ...

With which he meant to say that the phenomenon was peculiar, odd or strange.

The only other case I have ever seen this is in the movie title: "The Curious Case of Benjamin Button", but that might be 'artistic freedom' (since Curious Case has the nice C.. C..). My question is: is the usage of the word "curious" in the meaning of peculiar correct?

Comment: This is General Reference. Any dictionary will confirm the commonplace *peculiar, odd, strange* sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to use as "peculiar" although it might seem a little dated or facetious at the moment.

curious: "strange; unusual:"

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curious?q=curious (2)

mid-14c., "eager to know" (often in a bad sense), from Old French curios "solicitous, anxious, inquisitive; odd, strange" (Modern French curieux) and directly from Latin curiosus "careful, diligent; inquiring eagerly, meddlesome," akin to cura "care" (see cure (n.)). The objective sense of **"exciting curiosity"** is 1715 in English. In booksellers' catalogues, the word means "erotic, pornographic." *Curiouser and curiouser is from "Alice in Wonderland" (1865).*

http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=curious&searchmode=none